# Adding a nohup command to .profile

Tags: bash, startup, autostart, i3-wm, .profile

This has been annoying me for a while. There's this Polybar module called Greenclip that is equivalent to the clipboard icon we see in some DEs such as KDE. In order for it to work, I need to run the following command:

```
greenclip daemon
```

First, the process created by this command stopped after closing the terminal and didn't seem to even start when I added it to .profile. Then, `bg`/`disown -h` didn't work either and the process stopped again after the terminal closing. What worked was using `nohup', but I'm still struggling with the .profile problem. I definitely don't want to type this command myself every time I log in.

Can anyone tell me how can I get this command to run automatically on every login?

Comment: I don't think you should run it from any startup files associated with the terminal session. You should run it from some startup file associated with the GUI session itself, like `.xsession` or `.xsessionrc` maybe...